# What is "proxy a" in printtype function?

Tags: haskell

When I try to use `printtype` function from [Type.Showtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/show-type-0.1.1/docs/Type-Showtype.html). I find that the type signature of `printtype` is:

```
printtype :: Showtype a => proxy a -> IO ()
```

The confusing thing here is the type of `proxy a`, it seems come from [`Data.Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html), but I can't find any definition of `proxy`, it is obvious that is different to `Proxy`, because first letter of `proxy` is lower case. And I knew the first letter of data type cannot be lower case in Haskell, so `proxy a` is not a type, but why does it can appear in the type signature?

Comment: `proxy` is a type parameter. So something that is wrapped over `a`, `proxy` can be `[]`, `Maybe`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank for opinion, but `[]`, `Maybe` has definition in some package, but I can't find any definition of `proxy`. Does it not need be a type ?

Comment: It's indeed confusing at first, but note that `proxy` is lowercase, so it's just a type-level variable, like `a`. The type above is equivalent to `Showtype b => f b -> IO ()`, where `f` and `b` (like `proxy` and `a` in the original type) are two parameters, chosen by whoever calls `printtype`. For instance, one can choose `f = Maybe` and `a = Int`. More commonly, the caller chooses `f = Proxy` (uppercase!) which is defined as `data Proxy a = Proxy`, so that we can write `printtype (Proxy :: Proxy T)` for any concrete type `T` (of class `Showtype`).

Comment: Note that proxies are "a thing of the past", something used by older libraries. In modern Haskell, we would rather use the "ambiguous" type `printtype :: Showtype a => IO ()` which was not supported in the past by GHC. With that simpler type, we now can simply call `printtype @Int` to choose `a = Int`, without the need of a useless proxy argument (whose only purpose is to pass the chosen `a`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general a proxy for a type `a` is some data type `Proxy a` whose values carries no information. So the value is passed around to as a witness for its type (for type inference / type checking purposes). In that case `proxy` is isn't a specific data type, but a type variable with kind `* -> *`. Meaning you can use whatever you want as a proxy, but the idea remains the same.

The function is,

```
printtype :: Showtype a => proxy a -> IO ()
```

and it is supposed to "print a type", but functions are applied to values not types. So rather than passing an actual an argument of type `a` you pass an argument of some type `proxy a`, whose actual value is irrelevant (and usually will be a data type `Proxy` that contains no information).

Look at the instance for a simple type, e.g. pairs,

```
instance (Showtype a, Showtype b) => Showtype '(a,b) where
  showtype _ = showtuple' [
    showtype (Proxy :: Proxy a),
    showtype (Proxy :: Proxy b)]
```

First note how `showtype` ignores its argument,

```
showtype _ = ...
```

the value of the proxy is irrelevant, what matters is that we are printing the type `(a,b)`. Then we have a call to `showtuple'`, which is used to print types tuples (of any length) given a list with the printing of the types of each component. For each component we have,

```
showtype (Proxy :: Proxy a)
showtype (Proxy :: Proxy b)
```

the selected `proxy` here is the data type `Proxy` which holds no information. In one case it is of type `Proxy a` and in the other `Proxy b`. The function showtype is defined so that you could also call it with e.g.

```
showtype ([] :: [a])
showtype ([] :: [b])
```

Not that if you were passing around `a` rather than `proxy a`, here the only value you'd be able to construct (for a generic `a`) would be `undefined`. Should its evaluation ever be forced it would break your program.